# How to install geckodriver in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, python

I use Selenium in Python, I tried to run the webdriver function:

`default_browser = webdriver.Firefox()`

This Exception:

`WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.`

`geckodriver` in this site: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver

But how to install in Ubuntu 16.04 and can I fix this?

Comment: download , extract and add it to $PATH

Comment: Hi @rajeevmaash , Please fully explain, Thank you so much.

Comment: sudo apt-get install firefox-geckodriver

Comment: @MisterVerleg You should add it as an answer. Ubuntu has a package unlike Debian.

Comment: The `firefox-geckodriver` Ubuntu package no longer seems to be available as of Ubuntu 22.04: https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/web/firefox-geckodriver

Comment: @baptx I will thank you!

Comment: @countermeasure Indeed, I checked the packages but did not check what was the latest version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @baptx It seems, from looking into it a bit further, that doing a simple `sudo apt install firefox` on Ubuntu 22.04 will now also install geckodriver.

Comment: @countermeasure How is this possible if we don't see it in package files at https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/amd64/firefox/filelist?

Comment: @baptx I don't know, but I suspect it has something to do with Firefox now being installed as a `snap`, even when installed using `apt`. I'd also be interested to hear how this all works from someone who has some insight into that :)

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Here are the steps:

1. Go to the [geckodriver releases page](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases). Find the latest version of the driver for your platform and download it. For example:

   ```
   wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.24.0/geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux64.tar.gz
   ```
2. Extract the file with:

   ```
   tar -xvzf geckodriver*
   ```
3. Make it executable:

   ```
   chmod +x geckodriver
   ```
4. Add the driver to your PATH so other tools can find it:

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:/path-to-extracted-file/.
   ```

There are many ways to do this that will work. The above works for me on Ubuntu 16.10 64-bit.

Comment: Step 4 can be changed to `sudo mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin/`

Comment: Thanks @TulioCasagrande. Step 4 did not work for me but your command did.

Comment: There is `firefoxdriver` 3.8.0 package in Ubuntu Bionic, but it doesn't contain `geckodriver`, so doesn't work yet. The 2.x versions of these packages were able to launch Firefox, but weren't able to do anything.

Comment: note: `$PATH` should contains a directory such as `/usr/local/bin`. Don't put an executable such as `/path/to/geckodriver` there.

Comment: I have done everything right but forgot to install Firefox :-) If that is the case just run: `sudo apt-get install firefox`

Comment: Step 3 is redundant, we're downloading a gunzip not a zip file

Comment: In case anyone else is as stupid as me, remember not to literally export the path "/path-to-extracted-file/.". I wonder if that's why other people reported that step 4 didin't work for them. :/

Comment: In case you are using with Selenium, make sure that the versions of the geckodriver and Selenium are compatible.

Comment: @TulioCasagrandeAlberto this one is great , much better than any other solution!!!

Answer (score 32):

**Manual steps to install geckodriver on Ubuntu**:

- visit https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
- download the latest version of "geckodriver-vX.XX.X-linux64.tar.gz"
- unarchive the tarball (`tar -xvzf geckodriver-vX.XX.X-linux64.tar.gz`)
- give executable permissions to `geckodriver` (`chmod +x geckodriver`)
- move the `geckodriver` binary to `/usr/local/bin` or any location on your system PATH.

**Script to install geckodriver on Ubuntu**:

```
#!/bin/bash

INSTALL_DIR="/usr/local/bin"

json=$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/latest)
url=$(echo "$json" | jq -r '.assets[].browser_download_url | select(contains("linux64") and endswith("gz"))')
curl -s -L "$url" | tar -xz
chmod +x geckodriver
sudo mv geckodriver "$INSTALL_DIR"
echo "installed geckodriver binary in $INSTALL_DIR"
```

Comment: I didn't go through - had my own script - but this kind of serious scripting, using `jq` and avoiding at most hardcoded things should always be upvoted.

Comment: I like how you have used `jq` in the script to get the target URL

Comment: I installed it like this, thanks it works smoothly, then tested as a command, and that works.
But then I run selenium in the python script, and it raises the same exception: 

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Answer (score 24):

Webdriver installation (silent mode) that can be used in sysadmin scripts (bash/ansible).

```
## Geckodriver
wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.23.0/geckodriver-v0.23.0-linux64.tar.gz
sudo sh -c 'tar -x geckodriver -zf geckodriver-v0.23.0-linux64.tar.gz -O > /usr/bin/geckodriver'
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/geckodriver
rm geckodriver-v0.23.0-linux64.tar.gz

## Chromedriver
wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.29/chromedriver_linux64.zip
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
sudo chmod +x chromedriver
sudo mv chromedriver /usr/bin/
rm chromedriver_linux64.zip
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems that geckodriver version 0.16.1 is compatible with FF 52.4.0 (on Debian jessie) – geckodriver version 0.19 was not.

Comment: I prefer this over the fully automated script for my use case. First, it doesn't use jq which I don't have installed on my system. Second, it always installs a known version that I can test and verify works correctly for me.

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu 22.04, it seems that `geckodriver` is now installed when you install Firefox:

```
$ sudo apt install firefox
```

It seems that [the old firefox-geckodriver package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/web/firefox-geckodriver) has been dropped.

Comment: Thank you, I added your comment to my answer, but saw you made your own answer as well. if you want me to remove it please say so!

Comment: @MisterVerleg No problem at all. Let's leave both your answer and my answer up and let the sorting/ranking system take care of the rest. Seems like the easiest approach :)

Answer (score 3):

If you use the command line pre ubuntu 2.04:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox-geckodriver
```

Thanks to the comment of @countermeasure:

apparently installing firefox will also install gecko driver

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

Comment: In fact this worked at the time but the package is no longer available on latest Ubuntu versions, as mentioned by @countermeasure in the question comments.

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04, it seems that `sudo apt install firefox` will also install geckodriver. I'm guessing that might be why the `firefox-geckodriver` package was dropped.

Answer (score 1):

There are essentially three steps:

1. **download a release** from github
2. **unzip into the right directory**, namely `usr/local/bin` (can be merged into one line!)
3. **set executable permissions**.
   These steps should work for any Linux distribution (worked on my Debian 10). Here is the shell code:

```
wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.33.0/geckodriver-v0.33.0-linux64.tar.gz
sudo tar -xzvf geckodriver*tar.gz -C /usr/local/bin
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/geckodriver
```

As for newest versions of Ubuntu, it can be installed with `sudo apt-get install firefox`. Older versions accept `sudo apt-get install firefox-geckodriver`.

```
Package firefox-geckodriver is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  firefox
```