# how do I clone the geckodriver executable with git?

Tags: firefox, java, browser, git, wget

This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/871077/45156) helped me with [running Selenium](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/28408/8900).

now...why is the solution to use `wget`?  How do you know which is the latest version?  Why not use `git`?

Comment: No sane project adds binary executables to source control. You clone the source and build it.

Comment: All of your questions amount to weighing the benefits against the drawbacks of one or more options. What's better depends on the situation and to some extent personal preference. If you want to criticise the linked answer you're welcome to do so in its comment section. I'm voting to close this answer as too broad because it's basically asking why someone made a particular choice.

Answer (score 2):

You clone it the same way you would clone any Git repo.

```
git clone https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver
```

> why is the solution to use wget

`wget` is installed by default and `git` isn't.

> How do you know which is the latest version?

Look at [the releases page](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).

> Why not use  git?

See above.

Comment: that doesn't seem to clone the actual executable.

Comment: Why would anybody include an executable in source code?

Comment: Also, that repo uses weird branching: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/tree/release

Comment: Mozilla doesn't use GitHub for git hosting and geckodriver doesn't use git for version control anymore.  The source code for geckodriver is stored at mozilla-central in a Mercurial repo.  But cloning that repo would only get you the source code... so you would still need to setup a build environment and compile geckodriver yourself.  However, the geckodriver project does use GitHub for publishing releases of geckodriver in executable form that are built by Mozilla.  These files sit on a file server accessible via HTTP (not in a git repo).